# How do I check if all of a field are equal in a group in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause

So I have something like

```
 prop1 | prop2
 aaa   | xxx
 aaa   | xxx
 bbb   | yyy
 bbb   | !yyy
 ccc   | zzz
 ccc   | zzz
```

now I can group by prop1 and get aaa, bbb, ccc and I can check them individually  and find that bbb's two properties dont match,

So how do I do that with sql?

How do I only get 'bbb' as my result?

I may have 2 to many in each group.

Comment: Based on your sample data shown above, what would your expected output be?

Comment: What type of SQL?

Comment: just 'bbb' or if there was another row 'ddd|qqq, ddd|!qqq' I would get 'bbb' and 'ddd'

Comment: ...so would it just be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE prop1='bbb'`?

Comment: just 'bbb' or if there was another row 'ddd|qqq, ddd|!qqq' I would get 'bbb' and 'ddd'

Comment: do you mean `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY prop1, prop2 HAVING count(distinct prop2) > 1;` ?

Comment: No. I can group by Prop1 so SELECT Prop1 FROM table GROUP BY Prop1 and I I can get aaa, bbb, ccc but I want to know which ones have a different  Prop2. aaa and ccc both have the same Prop2 I want bbb with two different Prop2s

Comment: try `SELECT *,count(distinct prop2) as cnt FROM table GROUP BY prop1 having cnt>1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

`DISTINCT` on `prop1` and `prop2` remove duplicate data. then 
get `COUNT` greater than 1.

```
SELECT prop1    
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT prop1,prop2
  FROM t
)t
GROUP BY prop1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2a10c/1

Comment: This is both more complicated and less performant than necessary.

Answer (score 8):

I would simply use `group by` and `having`:

```
select prop1
from t
group by prop1
having min(prop2) <> max(prop2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your property 1 is your "key", the "proper" way to do this without nested queries is to use a left outer join. A left outer join will search one -or more- entries with the same property 1 and will return distinct property 1's where their corresponding property 2 values do not match. Here is an example:

```
select distinct fp.prop1
 from table1 as fp
 left outer join table1 as sp on fp.prop1 = sp.prop1 and fp.prop2 != sp.prop2
 where sp.prop2 is not null
```

And a SQLFiddle proving it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2729b/6

Basically, it's doing the following:

- Select Distinct (pretty self explantatory)
- From table 1 as fp (aliases table 1 to "fp" so you can query against table 1 a second time)
- Left outer join table 1 as sp (joins against the same table a second time, and queries against them to return the value only where the property 1 matches, and the property 2 doesnt)
- Where clause limits it to only return results where the left outer join is true (which is where the second property doesn't match)

If you have 100s of results in your property 2 and want to see the ones that don't match, add sp.prop2 into your select clause, and you'll get one results per non-matching value along with the property 1 it matches to.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your table `table1`. Then, the following query will give you the `prop1` that has more than 1 unique values (or, in other words, has different values of `prop2` for the same `prop1`) :

```
SELECT
    x.prop1,
    COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.prop1,
        t.prop2
    FROM
        table1 t
    GROUP BY
        t.prop1,
        t.prop2
) x
GROUP BY
    x.prop1
HAVING
    COUNT(1) > 1
```

This answer will also tell you how many different `prop2` values the relevant `prop1` has.

Comment: This will return all three `prop1` values.